# Xcode iOS UI tests crash with SIGABRT when multiple test classes exist

Tags: xcode, swift2, ios-simulator, xctest

I am developing an iOS app using XCUITest methods for testing the interface. I have a basic UI test set up in a first file `AppUITests.swift` which does `let app = XCUIApplication()` as member of the `XCTestCase` subclass, and later does `app.launch()` in the `setUp()` method. All is well for tests in this file.

I wanted to create a new test suite for UI tests JUST in the first main "mode" of the application, so I created a new file `MainModeUITests.swift` and copied the same code over. My plan of course was to test the UI workflows in this mode, but in this new file the application crashes with `signal SIGABRT` at the line where `XCUIApplication()` is called.

Currently I am testing on simulator and haven't even gotten to device testing yet. Any ideas why `SIGABRT` would be thrown at the application by the UITesting? Is there a reason why I can't call this in different test suites? Is there a way to even separate out UI tests into multiple swift files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out: I have two targets (one for unit tests, the other for UI tests). I had accidentally added the UI test file to the non-UI-test target, so when running tests from both targets, the XCUIApplication() method tried to access the app in a way that the unit tests, which don't use XCUITest, didn't like. Solution: remove all XCUITest sources from "Compile sources" on the other test target.